# How X++ run for D365 Form

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

In D365, I know how to run code for DataSource, DataField, and Control. But How can I run code "Run" "Init" for Form?

If I just write "Run" and "Init" under the Form level. Will it run automatically?
Or, I need some ways to call them?
How can I run this "Run" for my Form?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UrMC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could just try it yourself with a simple test form like this:

```
[Form]
public class TestForm1 extends FormRun
{
    void run()
    {
        info("test from run()");
        super();
    }
}
```

If you run it you will see the message appears.

As in previous editions (2009/2012) you can just look at the code the tooling would generate if you override the method as shown below:

[image: Tooling]

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing a custom form from scratch then yes, as @DAXaholic has pointed out you can override `run` and `init` methods directly on your form and then implement your custom logic there as you did in previous AX versions.

However overlayering is strongly [discouraged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/extensibility/migrate-overlayer-extension) in D365 and will no longer be supported by Microsoft. That means that if you are customizing a standard form or any other form which is not in the same package you have to use extensibility approach to implement custom logic. This can be achieved through [extensions](https://community.dynamics.com/365/financeandoperations/b/newdynamicsax/archive/2016/10/11/code-behind-extension-forms-how-to-add-state-variable-and-override-methods-without-overlayering) and [event handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/extensibility/customization-overlayering-extensions#form-extensions).

Suppose you have a form and you have to execute some code before and after the form is initialized. Instead of overlaying the object and overriding `init` method you can create an event handler class and subscribe to `OnInitializing` and `OnInitialized` events:

```
[FormEventHandler(formStr(Test), FormEventType::Initializing)]
public static void Test_OnInitializing(xFormRun sender, FormEventArgs e)
{
    // your code here
}

[FormEventHandler(formStr(Test), FormEventType::Initialized)]
public static void Test_OnInitialized(xFormRun sender, FormEventArgs e)
{
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through below docs. Its applicable for D365 form opening.You can override this form methods.
[Event Method Sequences when a Form is Opened](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/event-method-sequences-when-a-form-is-opened)